# How to specify the repository in apache dav svn?

Tags: apache, svn, webdav, mod-dav-svn

I have the following setup:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName svn.project1.com

    <Location />
       DAV svn
       SVNPath /svn
    </Location>
</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName svn.project2.com

    <Location />
       DAV svn
       SVNPath /svn
    </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

When I navigate to either http://svn.project1.com/ or http://svn.project1.com/, it gives a directory listing with both repositories:

```
Revision 1270: /

* project1/
* project2/

Powered by Subversion version 1.4.4 (r25188)
```

How do I get both hosts to point to their respective repositories?

I want to be able to use URLs like:

```
http://svn.project1.com/trunk/
```

Instead of:

```
http://svn.project1.com/project1/trunk/
```

And thus prevent access to e.g. project2 from project1 viz:

```
http://svn.project1.com/project2/
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works with `SVNPath /svn/project#`. But be aware, I think this only works if you really have two seperate repositories. As far as I can tell from your information, you're using one  repository for both projects.

Comment: Yes, they are both in the same repository - do I really have to mvoe them each to their own repository?

Comment: Yes, SVNPath only gives the physical path of the repository. So you can only address the repository root with a VirtualHost. Everything beyond that can only achieved by appending the path to the URL.

Answer (score 1):

```
<Location /svn/>
     DAV svn
     SVNParentPath "D:\repos"
     SVNListParentPath On
     AuthName "Subversion repository"
     SVNPathAuthz on
     AuthType SSPI
     SSPIAuth On
     SSPIAuthoritative On
     SSPIDomain RAILINC
     SSPIOfferBasic On
     SSPIUsernameCase lower
     SSPIOmitDomain On
     AuthzSVNAccessFile "D:\repos\svnaccessfile.txt"
     Require valid-user
</Location>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, but have you tried this?

```
SVNPath /svn/project1/
```

Comment: That didn't work:

  $ ls /svn
  conf  dav  db  format  hooks  locks  README.txt

- the repositories aren't mapped to the filesystem

Comment: Then your file system is seriously fubared. DavSVN isn't working magic when it comes up with the listing.

Comment: Run `find /svn -type d -print | sort` and update us with the structure (censoring names if you need to)

Comment: I think this is pretty standard - no project subdirectories present:

/svn
/svn/conf
/svn/dav
/svn/db
/svn/db/revprops
/svn/db/revs
/svn/db/transactions
/svn/db/transactions/6-1.txn
/svn/hooks
/svn/locks

Answer (score 0):

While using

```
SVNPath /svn/projectX/
```

should fix your problem, it will expose a serious flaw in DavSVN. The flaw that it has problems with being at the root directory of a domain. Getting random checkin errors that at present, have no solution available, was such a problem we had to switch from a subdomain to a subdirectory.